# Docker compose up, retry pull images

Tags: docker-compose, docker-command

We sometimes get `Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers` errors when running `docker-compose up` as its pulling images.

Is there a way to get docker-compose to retry when it is pulling an image?

Answer (score 1):

Using only `docker-compose`, **no**.

The `docker-compose` command does not specifically exposes a flag for retrying pulling the images, but you can always use bash magic for that:

```sh
while ! docker-compose pull; do sleep .1; done && docker-compose up
```