# Retrying in x seconds when use docker-compose build?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

i have  a problem with docker on my local machine and my internet provider. If i connect to another i don't have it error.
So, when i try to build the project

```
maxim@maxim-TM1701:~/dev/projects/buzz/back_new$ sudo docker-compose up
[sudo] password for maxim:
Building web
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.4
3.4: Pulling from library/python
55cbf04beb70: Pull complete
1607093a898c: Pull complete
9a8ea045c926: Pull complete
d4eee24d4dac: Pull complete
b59856e9f0ab: Downloading [==================================================>]  112.7MB/112.7MB
acbc9a5bd738: Download complete

2bedfced3d32: Download complete
35cfd5596113: Download complete
54603c381292: Download complete
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: read tcp 192.168.31.82:48810->104.18.125.25:443: read: connection reset by peer
maxim@maxim-TM1701:~/dev/projects/buzz/back_new$ sudo docker-compose up
Building web
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.4
3.4: Pulling from library/python
55cbf04beb70: Retrying in 2 seconds
1607093a898c: Download complete
9a8ea045c926: Download complete
d4eee24d4dac: Downloading [===========>                                       ]  7.998MB/34.33MB
b59856e9f0ab: Downloading [=>                                                 ]  4.267MB/189.1MB
acbc9a5bd738: Waiting
2bedfced3d32: Waiting
35cfd5596113: Waiting
54603c381292: Waiting
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Please post formatted text, not pictures of text.

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415167/docker-compose-up-retry-pull-images